# Fancybox - Multiple PDF - Unable to scroll up and down in document

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox, but when I have an array of PDF images, the navigation arrows allowing you to change between pdf documents overlay ontop of the PDF controls stopping users from scrollign through the document etc.

I have created a fiddle showing the problem, I would greatly appreciate any help.

regards

Tom

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomwilliams/g4VdE/2/)

```
<a class="fancybox">Click to show pdf</a>
```

```
$(".fancybox").click(function(){
var photoArray = [];
photoArray.push({ href: 'http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf' , type: 'iframe' });
 photoArray.push({ href: 'http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf' , type: 'iframe' });
 photoArray.push({ href: 'http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf' , type: 'iframe' });
 photoArray.push({ href: 'http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf' , type: 'iframe' });


$('.fancy').fancybox();
        $.fancybox.open(photoArray, {
            'openEffect': 'elastic',
            'closeEffect': 'elastic',
            'nextEffect': 'fade',
            'openSpeed': 600,
            'closeSpeed': 200,
                autoSize : false,
                beforeLoad : function() {                    
                    this.width = 1000;  
                    this.height = 800;
                },
                helpers: {
                    overlay: null
                //buttons: {}
            },
                iframe: {
                    preload: false
                }
        });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-prev {
        left: -70px;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        vertical-align: central;
        top: 50%;
    }

    .fancybox-next {
        right: -70px;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        top: 50%;
    }

    .fancybox-nav span {
        visibility: visible;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the "arrows" for the box are overlaying the scrollbar.  There are two approaches:

1) Remove the arrows.

Just add this to the fancybox:

```
"arrows" : false
```

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4VdE/3/) showing the difference.

2) Style the arrows

That'll take more work, but you could try to move them, add padding, etc.  Regardless, I believe that they will cause problems and the best bet is to just drop them altogether.

Comment: Removing the arrows may not be a good idea. I would rather think the options are 1). use the buttons helper or 2). move the arrows as suggested at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.5

Comment: @JFK It might not be a good idea.  But at this level ("Why can't I scroll?"), I was just trying to point to the problem.  I'm sure there are several ways to style/move/arrange the arrows, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: I am not trying to start an argument here but if you remove the arrows, then you may not be able to navigate through the items in the gallery ... you patched a hole but opened a new one ;) Then you suggest to style the arrows but you don't provide a way to do it and at the end, your conclusion is that is a problematic solution so the best is "drop them altogether" ... how come this can be an accepted answer? just wondering ;)

Comment: @JFK That's presuming that `user2039547` want the left-right navigation functionality.  In the end, the answer I'm trying to provide is simply "The arrows are getting in the way".  I'm not really offering the code to fix the problem.  "How to move the arrows" or "How to style the arrows" are really a separate questions. If `user2039547` is interested, he/she could just ask another question.  I agree this may not be the best answer, but without information about what they want, I'm not going to spend a lot of time on this. (especially for `user2039547`)

Comment: Last comment : I am not assuming anything, the OP for sure needs/wants the navigation arrows otherwise what is the purpose of pushing the items inside an array if you can only display one?

Comment: @JFK Please, I encourage you to write your own answer.

Comment: Read my very first comment.